# asp.net Core Razor CRUD - wont accept any input for Phone as valid

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, crud, razor-pages

I'm building an app using Razor pages and the built in CRUD pages.  I have a code-first setup with SQL Express and in my Location table I have a nullable int col named 'Phone'.  My Location Class is very straight forward with

```
    [Column("Phone")]
    public Nullable<int>  Phone { get; set; }
```

and my Context class is simple too

```
   public DbSet<Location> Location { get; set; }
```

My auto generated CRUD Edit page looks like

```
    <input asp-for="Location.City" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Location.City" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Location.State" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Location.State" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Location.State" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Location.Zip" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Location.Zip" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Location.Zip" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Location.Phone" data-val="false" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Location.Phone" data-val="false" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Location.Phone" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
```

I don't see that I told VS this is a Phone format and everything else saves except for the phone number.  When I put anything in 5554443333 or whatever, I get:  "The value '5554443333' is not valid for Phone." from asp-validation.  If I leave the phone field blank, everything else saves properly.  I'll put in a little regEx to handle dashes, parenthesis, and spaces later.  I just need help in finding how to either turn off or tone down the validation for this field.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the phone property to string and try to use regex for validation:

```
[Column("Phone")]
[RegularExpression(@"^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$", ErrorMessage = "Not a valid phone number")]
public string Phone { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the range of int type is `-2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647`, and your input has exceeded this range, it is recommended that you use `string` or `long` type.

```
 [Column("Phone")]
public string? Phone { get; set; }
```

Comment: Hi @BrianTremelling,any update about this case?

Comment: Works great, thank you.  I saw a tutorial from a guy who said one should use int for phone but that really threw me there for a bit.

Comment: Hi @BrianTremelling,Can you give the reason why you mark others instead of me?

Comment: Sorry, you were both correct but he was first.  If I was allowed to upvote I would, I'm just too new to StackO

Comment: Hi @BrianTremelling, If you can see the time, you can find that I answered the question first. :)